# Программа не видит путь к файлу C:\Windows\ System32\nslookup.exe

Tags: c#, windows, файлы, path

Программа не видит путь к файлу C:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe
Проверка естественно всегда выдает "Путь не найден". То же самое происходит и например с путем к фалу notepad.exe в этой же папке, но при этом если обратиться к файлу C:\Windows\twin_32.dll то программа его находит.
Подскажите куда копать? Нужно назначить текущего пользователя владельцем папки System32?

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe"))
{
Console.WriteLine("Путь найден");
}
else Console.WriteLine("Путь не найден");
```

Comment: « Нужно назначить текущего пользователя владельцем папки System32?» — а давайте без деструктивных действий?

Comment: Скорее всего происходит перенаправление в "специальную" папку: ваша 32-битная программа работает в 64-битной винде и происходит перенаправление туда, где файла нет.

Comment: Скорее всего у пользователя, от которого вы запускаете программу просто не хватает прав на чтение файла

Comment: @lDrakonl проверка существования - ни разу не чтение, дело не в правах. Уж на запуск notepad прав у всех должно хватать :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а прав на чтение родительской папки для проверки существования не надо ли?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов `nslookup ` - это не `notepad`, а командная строка для общения с `dns-сервером`. Насколько я помню, по умолчанию доступ в папку `Widows\System32` закрыт для простых пользователей начиная с `Win7`

Comment: @lDrakonl там доступ закрыт только в Проводнике. Программный доступ на чтение - остается, ведь именно для него эта папка и делалась...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в File System Redirector'е (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx)

Если кратко, %windir%\System32 - для 64-битных приложений. 32-битные приложения система перенаправляет в %windir%\SysWOW64 где вашего файла вполне может и не быть.

Comment: у ТС написан абсолютный путь. Перенаправление все равно срабатывает?

Comment: Ответ неполный без описания как это перенаправление обойти. Например, через %windir%\Sysnative...

Comment: @lDrakonl сработает, инфа 146%

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вариантов решения проблемы несколько, начиная от сборки 64-битного приложения, заканчивая использованием Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection().

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вот их бы в ответе и перечислить

Comment: Коллеги, у меня на Windows 7 есть как C:\Windows\System32\nslookup.exe, так и C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nslookup.exe.

Comment: @VladD Но из этого не следует, что у автора должно быть так же.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Ну это да.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо, Владимир, действительно помогло использование Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()

Answer (score 1):

Используйте путь из переменных окружения

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "nslookup.exe")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Путь найден");
}
else Console.WriteLine("Путь не найден");
```

Comment: пытался и через переменные окружения, и через абсолютный путь, результат один